# selenium ide type command

Tags: selenium, types, ide, command

I've recorded activity on selenium IDE 2.9.1 with Firefox 54. When I run this activity it gives me an error.

The log of activity is

```
Executing: |type | id=login-email | super@admin.com |
```

The error is

```
Element css=a.dropdown-toggle.user-details not found
```

Now the issue is, the value (super@admin.com) is not inserted in login-email field. So it throws an error.

I've tried type, typeKeys and sendKeys commands. But nothing seems to work. What can I do to insert value?

Comment: Of-coarse the error from the element `css=a.dropdown-toggle.user-details` is not similar to the element you have shared as `type | id=login-email`

Comment: @DebanjanB I understand that. But the value itself is not inserting into the field.

Comment: But asking solution for _usecase_ **A** and sharing error of _usecase_ **B** doesn't elps us to debug the error.

Comment: I’m asking solutions for usecase A itself, if you read the question properly.

Comment: @NicEndo So can you suggest the solution of the issue?